# Controlling OpenHAB using Amazon Echo on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, macos, jar, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I am running `OpenHAB` within `Raspberry Pi` and I saved the `.jar` file in my OS X and I run it within OS X terminal and I get the following error. Can you please let me know how I can fix that?

```
java -jar amazon-echo-bridge-0.2.1.jar –upnp.config.address=192.168.1.105
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/armzilla/ha/SpringbootEntry : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:163)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:136)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have downloaded the jar file from [here](https://github.com/armzilla/amazon-echo-ha-bridge/releases/tag/v0.2.1) and I am following [this tutorial](http://tinsley.io/2015/06/control-your-items-using-the-amazon-echo-openhab/).

The jar runs within Raspbian but I was hoping to run it from OS X because [I cannot install Chromium on Raspbian.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41603/installing-chrome-on-raspbian)

However even when running within Raspbian I get this error:

```
asticsearchAutoConfiguration : Closing Elasticsearch client
2016-01-24 23:07:58.279  INFO 2411 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Bres] stopping ...
2016-01-24 23:07:58.336  INFO 2411 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Bres] stopped
2016-01-24 23:07:58.337  INFO 2411 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Bres] closing ...
2016-01-24 23:07:58.413  INFO 2411 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Bres] closed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.armzilla.ha.SpringbootEntry.main(SpringbootEntry.java:14)
    ... 6 more
pi@raspberrypi /opt/openhab/echo $
```

Comment: This question is helpful for people who are going to work with this API. Please don't vote down out of courtesy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mona,

You're trying to run the Jar file using Java 7, while it was designed to run on Java 8.  Install Java 8 and run the Jar using that to fix the error.

Comment: in my Raspberry Pi I have Java 8 :
`pi@raspberrypi /opt/openhab/echo $ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)`

Comment: Your Raspberry Pi is running into a different error which doesn't have the same cause.  Check my response to your comment on my blog for a suggestion.